# How to select columns that are not na

Tags: r, dataframe

im new to R and i know how to filter by number by na, but i dont know how to filter a dataframe by certain value of its cells.

ex:

```
<chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <int>   <int>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
1   2020.02.29. 116 0   0   0   0   ... ... ... ... 
2   2020.03.01. 10  0   0   0   0   ... ... ... ...
```

i want to select the columns with the value of "..."

Is there something like df$column == '...' without telling what column so it checks it all?

so i just can

```
delete <- df[{where column=='...'}]
```

Someone asked about the dput of the dataframe, here it is

```
dput(csv[sample(nrow(csv), 50), ])
structure(list(Datums = c("2021.01.06.", "2022.01.19.", 
"2021.10.24.", 
"2021.12.20.", "2020.05.15.", "2021.10.21.", "2022.01.20.", "2021.10.10.", 
"2020.10.05.", "2021.02.21.", "2020.10.17.", "2021.04.19.", "2021.01.18.", 
"2021.10.23.", "2022.01.15.", "2021.03.02.", "2020.12.13.", "2020.05.05.", 
"2020.11.17.", "2021.08.20.", "2020.07.27.", "2021.04.24.", "2020.05.31.", 
"2022.01.26.", "2021.07.08.", "2020.12.16.", "2020.05.30.", "2020.11.07.", 
"2020.12.24.", "2020.09.23.", "2020.05.04.", "2020.05.21.", "2022.01.21.", 
"2021.12.09.", "2021.11.18.", "2020.05.11.", "2021.12.08.", "2020.08.25.", 
"2020.11.05.", "2021.12.29.", "2021.12.02.", "2022.01.25.", "2021.09.06.", 
"2020.05.17.", "2021.03.13.", "2020.10.07.", "2020.03.07.", "2020.06.11.", 
"2021.08.06.", "2020.05.10."), TestuSkaits = c("13946", "22489", 
"11246", "4933", "2156", "24642", "23669", "14606", "1748", "4819", 
"5332", "2683", "3423", "20218", "21269", "14225", "5391", "686", 
"6059", "9231", "801", "14961", "897", "28009", "6700", "9887", 
"1243", "6651", "11597", "2733", "1219", "1870", "25399", "11714", 
"12708", "555", "11389", "2130", "7564", "9906", "11014", "23504", 
"7677", "1028", "13870", "4426", "14", "1581", "7385", "1021"
), ApstiprinataCOVID19InfekcijaSkaits = c("1229", "5082", "2252", 
"326", "8", "2935", "4885", "1359", "40", "410", "188", "202", 
"244", "2932", "3065", "645", "629", "0", "278", "133", "0", 
"711", "1", "9143", "50", "1023", "1", "404", "1270", "12", "17", 
"9", "5972", "793", "1221", "7", "796", "5", "367", "1319", "712", 
"6097", "114", "11", "578", "67", "0", "2", "80", "9"), Ipatsvars = c("8,8", 
"22,6", "20", "6,6", "0,4", "11,9", "20,6", "9,3", "2,3", "8,5", 
"3,5", "7,5", "7,1", "14,5", "14,4", "4,5", "11,7", "0", "4,6", 
"1,4", "0", "4,8", "0,1", "32,6", "0,7", "10,3", "0,1", "6,1", 
"11", "0,4", "1,4", "0,5", "23,5", "6,8", "9,6", "1,3", "7", 
"0,2", "4,9", "13,3", "6,5", "25,9", "1,5", "1,1", "4,2", "1,5", 
"0", "0,1", "1,1", "0,9"), IzarstetoPacientuSkaits = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
24L, 0L, 0L), MirusoPersonuSkaits = c(32L, 17L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 
23L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 26L, 14L, 17L, 25L, 0L, 6L, 
1L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 25L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 24L, 
26L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 3L, 24L, 19L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L), ApstiprinatiVecGr_0.9Gadi = c("9", "779", "213", "41", 
"0", "256", "694", "181", "0", "11", "19", "9", "2", "275", "474", 
"36", "13", "0", "3", "17", "0", "34", "0", "1386", "9", "19", 
"0", "7", "38", "1", "0", "1", "932", "120", "162", "0", "117", 
"0", "10", "151", "107", "1077", "8", "0", "30", "4", "...", 
"0", "5", "0"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_10.19Gadi = c("61", "1430", 
"294", "74", "0", "503", "1287", "310", "4", "29", "29", "14", 
"4", "393", "799", "32", "36", "0", "15", "18", "0", "63", "0", 
"2178", "4", "34", "0", "34", "56", "1", "0", "0", "1522", "155", 
"165", "0", "174", "0", "27", "163", "140", "1722", "9", "0", 
"38", "7", "...", "0", "9", "2"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_20.29Gadi = c("160", 
"506", "183", "34", "1", "261", "515", "83", "3", "56", "35", 
"26", "36", "278", "338", "62", "73", "0", "27", "22", "0", "95", 
"0", "875", "8", "84", "1", "58", "130", "0", "0", "1", "549", 
"60", "130", "0", "51", "3", "36", "161", "52", "478", "21", 
"0", "63", "12", "...", "1", "10", "0"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_30.39Gadi = c("220", 
"829", "464", "73", "2", "525", "930", "209", "2", "67", "29", 
"37", "42", "597", "527", "125", "88", "0", "79", "22", "0", 
"158", "1", "1721", "4", "150", "0", "64", "233", "1", "1", "2", 
"1089", "150", "216", "1", "127", "0", "51", "294", "115", "1108", 
"17", "1", "112", "9", "...", "1", "20", "1"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_40.49Gadi = c("216", 
"717", "377", "41", "0", "527", "699", "190", "12", "69", "21", 
"45", "43", "537", "387", "129", "97", "0", "42", "21", "0", 
"124", "0", "1425", "11", "162", "0", "79", "207", "2", "1", 
"1", "915", "104", "177", "1", "118", "0", "74", "231", "115", 
"827", "27", "2", "96", "13", "...", "0", "12", "0"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_50.59Gadi = c("246", 
"411", "295", "32", "1", "371", "409", "154", "7", "75", "21", 
"25", "40", "392", "273", "119", "106", "0", "46", "11", "0", 
"98", "0", "802", "7", "178", "0", "79", "242", "4", "4", "2", 
"507", "83", "139", "0", "85", "2", "53", "164", "64", "476", 
"17", "1", "99", "10", "...", "0", "14", "0"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_60.69Gadi = c("179", 
"253", "232", "12", "0", "273", "238", "138", "9", "42", "21", 
"27", "44", "258", "165", "87", "102", "0", "42", "16", "0", 
"79", "0", "511", "5", "179", "0", "53", "192", "2", "6", "0", 
"278", "68", "115", "4", "67", "0", "46", "87", "56", "275", 
"10", "4", "89", "7", "...", "0", "5", "4"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_70GadiUnVairak = c("138", 
"157", "194", "19", "4", "219", "113", "94", "3", "61", "13", 
"19", "33", "202", "102", "55", "114", "0", "24", "6", "0", "60", 
"0", "245", "2", "217", "0", "30", "172", "1", "5", "2", "180", 
"53", "117", "1", "57", "0", "70", "68", "63", "134", "5", "3", 
"51", "5", "...", "0", "5", "2"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_70.79Gadi = c("73", 
"100", "97", "10", "3", "127", "71", "53", "2", "42", "10", "12", 
"19", "129", "61", "46", "65", "0", "12", "4", "0", "37", "0", 
"172", "2", "103", "0", "20", "100", "0", "1", "1", "126", "27", 
"66", "1", "30", "0", "29", "39", "40", "91", "3", "2", "37", 
"3", "...", "0", "3", "0"), ApstiprinatiVecGr_80GadiUnVairak = c("65", 
"57", "97", "9", "1", "92", "42", "41", "1", "19", "3", "7", 
"14", "73", "41", "9", "49", "0", "12", "2", "0", "23", "0", 
"73", "0", "114", "0", "10", "72", "1", "4", "1", "54", "26", 
"51", "0", "27", "0", "41", "29", "23", "43", "2", "1", "14", 
"2", "...", "0", "2", "2"), IzveselojusosSkaits = c(33005L, 276542L, 
168475L, 253282L, 662L, 163770L, 278524L, 152102L, 1307L, 70461L, 
1329L, 102290L, 42426L, 167123L, 272264L, 76211L, 16778L, 348L, 
1557L, 136725L, 1045L, 105254L, 745L, 288705L, 134610L, 18153L, 
745L, 1466L, 23402L, 1248L, 348L, 694L, 280384L, 246049L, 223459L, 
464L, 244974L, 1135L, 1444L, 259623L, 240660L, 286288L, 138549L, 
662L, 84196L, 1322L, 1L, 818L, 135833L, 464L), X14DienuKumulativaSaslimstibaUz100000Iedzivotaju = c(612.6, 
1742.4, 1653.1, 523.2, 5.2, 1463.3, 1895.1, 871, 31.3, 509.5, 
71.5, 383.3, 670.4, 1605.9, 1310.6, 493.1, 453.1, 7.7, 233.1, 
79.2, 2.3, 404.4, 3, 3239.9, 36.3, 474.9, 3.5, 177.8, 575.4, 
6.7, 8.2, 6, 2111.4, 521.7, 935, 6.7, 537.6, 2.6, 164.6, 540.9, 
572.6, 2885.8, 185.6, 6.7, 402.3, 35.9, 0, 1.7, 47.6, 6.6), ApstCOVID19InfSk_NevakcVakcNepab = c("...", 
"...", "1697", "...", "...", "2265", "...", "1071", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "2194", "\x85", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"114", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "97", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "..."), ApstCOVID19InfSk_Vakc = c("...", 
"2893", "555", "169", "...", "670", "2903", "288", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "738", "1695", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"19", "...", "...", "...", "5139", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "3441", "348", "456", "...", "358", 
"...", "...", "737", "289", "3296", "17", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "..."), ApstCOVID19InfSk_VakcNepab = c("...", 
"145", "...", "5", "...", "...", "125", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "85", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "407", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "187", "19", "90", "...", "21", "...", 
"...", "27", "26", "266", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "..."), ApstCOVID19InfSk_Nevakc = c("...", "2044", 
"...", "152", "...", "...", "1857", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "1285", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "3597", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "2344", "426", "675", "...", "417", "...", 
"...", "555", "397", "2535", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "..."), MirusoPersonuSkaits_NevakcVakcNepab = c("...", 
"11", "...", "7", "...", "...", "9", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "10", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "10", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "6", "23", "19", "...", "19", "...", "...", 
"19", "19", "12", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"..."), MirusoPersonuSkaits_Vakc = c("...", "6", "...", "3", 
"...", "...", "5", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "4", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "4", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "3", "1", "7", "...", "6", "...", "...", "5", "0", "3", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...")), row.names = c(313L, 
691L, 604L, 661L, 77L, 601L, 692L, 590L, 220L, 359L, 232L, 416L, 
325L, 603L, 687L, 368L, 289L, 67L, 263L, 539L, 150L, 421L, 93L, 
698L, 496L, 292L, 92L, 253L, 300L, 208L, 66L, 83L, 693L, 650L, 
629L, 73L, 649L, 179L, 251L, 670L, 643L, 697L, 556L, 79L, 379L, 
222L, 8L, 104L, 525L, 72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the columns if all rows are equal to "..."?

Comment: no, because theres no info there

Comment: You're not clear. Because it's written 'i want to select the columns with the value of "..."'

Comment: i want to select them so i can do df <- df[!delete] or something like that, sorry im very new to this

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(where(\(x) all(x == "..."))) #keep all columns that contains only "..." at every row
```

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous, but I think OP wants to delete these

Comment: When i execute that code i get this error: Warning message in rbind(parts$upper, chars$ellip_v, parts$lower, deparse.level = 0L):
“number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”

Comment: Can you show the output of `dput(df)` so we can see your data?

Comment: Check that `df` is a dataframe

Comment: dput(df) output is too long to post here

Comment: `dput(df[sample(nrow(df), 50), ]`

Comment: Post updated with the dput

Comment: @RafaCuberos There is no column with only "..."

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows where there are "..." in a column?

Comment: Yes, in the head(csv) i saw a lot of ... but you may be right there are not only '...' columns. So i guess i want to delete the rows now not the columns. I just want to clean the data, my first time using R and Stackoverflow so im sorry for being this messy.

Answer (score 0):

df[,apply(df, 2, FUN = function(vec) all(vec == '...'))]

Comment: doesnt work for me:
“number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).